# how to fix Could not determine java version from '11.0.1'. gradlew

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

When I run `gradlew` for anything it does not work even for --version
it says

> "Could not determine java version from '11.0.1'."

Also I'm using eclipse.

Comment: Probably related with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55847497/how-do-i-troubleshoot-inconsistency-detected-dl-lookup-c-111-java-result-12/55849728#55849728

Comment: Alongside that, minecraft doesn't even support Java 11 yet, lwjgl will completely break because of the lack of `sun.misc.Unsafe`

Comment: i downgraded to java 8 and i built everything but now eclipse says "a JRE or java development kit must be available in order to run eclipse No java virtual machine was found after searching C:/Program FIles/java/jdk-11.0.1/bin"