# Libgdx desktop does not run - WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

Tags: java, gradle, libgdx, lwjgl

I'm following this tutorial (http://www.kilobolt.com/day-2-setting-up-libgdx.html). But in step 18 where I run the project as a java application, I get the following errors:

[image]

I've tried looking around but found no solution for the errors i had.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Running a `java --version` returns

```
openjdk 11.0.4 2019-07-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.4+11-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu218.04.3, mixed mode, sharing)
```

My libgdx version is 1.9.10 which i think is the newest?

Comment: Can you please copy & paste the full error instead of making a screenshot that is incomplete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of `libgdx` and `java` are you using?

---

For the error check this [`question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55847497/how-do-i-troubleshoot-inconsistency-detected-dl-lookup-c-111-java-result-12)

Like you the questioner used libgdx under ubuntu with a newer version of the `open jdk`.
Downgrading to version 8 seemed to have resolved that issue.

---

The warnings basically says something along the lines that the underlying code uses functionality that has been deprecated and is pending for removal. Using a newer version of libgdx might solves that issue.

However some of those issues might not be resolved as `libgdx` does not seem to be under (much) active development anymore. The usual recommondetation is to not use anything beyond `JDK 8`.

According to the repo (for example [`this`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.badlogicgames.gdx/gdx)) `1.9.10` is indeed the latest version.

Note as well that those are just warnings you could potentially igore.
However as your are facing other issues with the open-jdk implementation ignoring them is not an option for you.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I edited the original post. Are the warnings ignorable though? In the kilobolt site a window pooped up with an image but in mine there was no window with image. I think its because of the errors?

Comment: I adjusted the wording of the answer a bit to point out that using anything beyond `java 8` is not really recommended.

Comment: "...as libgdx does not seem to be under (much) active development anymore" -- Why do you say that? There is a very active community on Discord and last commit was 19 hours ago as of this writing. Major version is also on to 1.10 since this post was created.