# Alice 3 crashing upon opening in Linux Mint 19.2

Tags: crash, alice

Alice 3 crashes every time I open it and select a default scene.
OS: Linux Mint 19.2
Terminal output:

```
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
version: 3.5.0.0+build229
investigate: hierarchyChanged seems to not be actually changing the parent 
org.alice.ide.uricontent.BlankSlateProjectLoader@5cf4fe43
note invoke later showCard null
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-lookup.c: 111: check_match: Assertion `version->filename == NULL || ! _dl_name_match_p (version->filename, map)' failed!
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen for all the starter scenes? The room has a distinct code path that could be a source of the problem.

There is also a newer beta version of Alice available. Loading has not been changed significantly in it, but it might help.

Comment: Alice is still on Java 8, so you may need to downgrade as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55849728) about “Inconsistency detected: dl-lookup.c: 111”