# What are the advantages of installing Eclipse Temurin OpenJDK in place of OpenJDK Deb Package on Debian?

Tags: java, adoptopenjdk, debian-packaging

I have on my Debian 11 Bullseye these JDK installed :

```
sudo update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64      1111       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

I want to switch to OpenJDK 17 and would to know if the Eclipse Temurin OpenJDK 17 is preferable to install instead of deb OpenJDK 17 package?
NB: Temurin advantages according to [Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/) are :

> supports high-quality, TCK certified runtimes and associated
> technology for use across the Java™ ecosystem

Comment: IMHO this is mostly opinion based. If you just want to work with Java 17 use whatever is easiest to install. If you need to decide between the various versions because of performance constraints then you need to do performance tests with different versions and realistic work loads.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas! Because I want to use the Temurin OpendJDK, so in which directory can I move the extracted openJDK archive file (more suitable directory)? NB: The directory **usr/lib/jvm** hold only (and deny archive file) jdk installed with apt-get

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know. I only ever installed debian openjdk packages on debian machines.

Comment: Finally I found the solution. You have to create a jdk folder in the opt directory (opt/jdk). See this link [Install JDK from targz](https://gist.github.com/filipelenfers/ef3f593deb0751944bb54b744bcac074)

Answer (score 3):

**As a rule of thumb**, just stick with what the official Debian repositories provide to be sure to receive regular updates and more important: Security updates released by the Debian project.

Before you resort to unpack tarballs into whatever location you should watch out for a maintained repository.

In case of Adoptium you might want to add their official repository that has been published on 2021-12-30.
https://blog.adoptium.net/2021/12/eclipse-temurin-linux-installers-available/

```
wget -O - https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/api/gpg/key/public \
    | apt-key add -

echo "deb https://packages.adoptium.net/artifactory/deb bullseye main" \
    > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/adoptium.list

apt update && apt install temurin-17-jdk
```

**TCK certification** might be worth only if you intend to ship commercial software to industry customers which insist on it.

Answer (score 0):

lwjgl [had issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64135865/515655) with non-Adoptium JVMs from 11 onward. They seem to have [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67439944/515655) it with version 3.

As for this writing, JOGL also has this issue but [does not have a fix](https://forum.jogamp.org/Inconsistency-detected-by-ld-so-dl-lookup-c-td4040188.html) AFAIK.

Comment: It's plain wrong, it was already fixed in JOGL 2.4.0 when you wrote your post. Please stop disparaging JogAmp projects.